# Does it cost money to transfer between google cloud and google drive?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am interested in running some code on Google's Compute Engine (or App Engine) that will read data from Google Cloud Storage and write it into Google Drive.

It appears from Google's pricing pages that accessing Google cloud services in the same region does not incur network transit costs (see https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing), but what is left unclear to me is if Google Drive is considered to be a cloud service in the same region or not.

Can anybody answer definitively (with reference preferably) if transferring data from Google Cloud Compute/App Engine into Google Drive is free of charge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transferring data from Google Cloud Storage to Google Drive using Google Compute Engine consists of two separate operations:

1. **Downloading objects from GCS to GCE.** As documented on the [GCS pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing), network egress to a Google service in the same region (GCE is a Google service) will be free. For example, downloading from a GCS US bucket to a GCE VM in us-central1-a will be free. Downloading from a GCS EU bucket to a GCE VM in us-central1-a will incur charges. Downloading from a [GCS regional bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/regional-buckets) located in US-CENTRAL1 to a VM in us-central1-a will be free. Downloading from a GCS regional bucket located in US-CENTRAL1 to a VM in asia-east1-a will incur charges.
2. **Uploading to Drive from GCE.** As mentioned on the [GCE pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#general), network egress from a VM to Google products (Drive is explicitly listed as an example) is free.

Comment: in the interest of completeness: you do note that it's mentioned as an example of a Google Product, and it is listed as free, but there is also an asterisk with a note that it is "Promotional Pricing". Note sure if that means they intend to start charging soon or if it becomes too costly for them, etc. etc

Comment: That's true, but any change in the promotional pricing will be announced.

Comment: how does one determine the zone of the account? is there a way to choose it?

Comment: The 'promotional pricing' asterisk has been removed. It would seem egress to Drive will be free for the foreseeable future.