# What is the cost of reads/writes to Google Drive from Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm trying to cost a model where my app in GAE reads/writes data on behalf of my user, who is logged in with his/her Google Account.

After asking the user permission to use his/her Google Drive, I expect to get a token that I'll be able to use to make API calls to Google Drive.

What is not clear to me is whether I will be billed for reads and writes to that Google Drive on behalf of the user. There will be ingress & egress between GDrive and GAE as the user calls my GAE APIs.

What are the costs to be expected and is there any difference based on the region where my app is deployed?

Comment: I think this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514529/5995040) will help you clarify things regarding GAE and Google Drive. If you are only writing/reading from GAE to Drive it would be free(Egress to Google products (such as YouTube, Maps, Drive)). Regarding to the region, I'm not particularly sure on how  they determine the region of the app deployed. You can also try contacting their [support](https://cloud.google.com/support/) for an official statement regarding this topic. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Google Drive cost is only associated to [storage size](https://www.google.com/drive/pricing/).

App Engine cost is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs). You will be billed by running instances, use of the Search API and other resources. Read the details and focus on the ones you intend to use.

APIs are free but have a limited quota, which you have to take into account, as you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas) for Management and Reporting APIs.